# Pandas dataframe, ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm using the scikit-learn preprocessing and random forest ensemble techniques on a Pandas dataframe of 400,000 x 600 sized dataframe (800MB). I get this value error when I pass this dataframe through the algorithms, possibly due to extra spaces somewhere in the dataframe.
How do I clean all the spaces from my dataframe that should only contain numerical values, and absolutely no strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the data frame to a different type.

For instance the data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [5,7,9], 'y':[3,1,'2 ']})
```

Has an extra space in the last value.  This will store the `y` column as an object instead of a integer array.  To convert it you can use either:

```
df = df.astype(int)     # this
df = df.astype(float)   # or this
```

This will convert the entire data frame to the given type.  The other way to handle it is when the file is read (assuming you are reading a csv or other format).